# $f:\mathbb {R}^2 \to \mathbb {R}$, $f(x,y) = \lvert x \rvert y$. Does $df(1,0)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb {R}^2 \to \mathbb {R}$, $f(x,y) = \lvert x \rvert y$

I know that $\frac {\partial }{\partial y} f$ exists in $\mathbb {R}^2$ and that $\frac {\partial }{\partial x} f$ doesn't exist in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Does $df(1,0)$ exist?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) an try editing your post. Without any improvement, others may not be interested in answering, and the question may get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_x$ exists at any $(x_0,0)$ type point:
$$\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x+x_0,0)-f(x_0,0)}{x}=\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{|x+x_0|\cdot 0-|x_0| \cdot 0}{x}=0$$

As we have $f_x(1,0)=0, f_y(1,0)=1$, then for differentiation
$$\frac{|x|y-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \to  0$$

when $(x,y) \to (1,0)$.